# Optimal way to store leaderboards by month

Tags: database-design, backup

I have a leaderboard table of users for current month. I need to save all leaderboards by months and display current/old leaderboard on site. Should i create a new table when every month stars? Is this a good approach? In two years i will have 24 additional tables in my database which is really confusing me.
What is optimal way to do this?

Comment: What server are you using? Show us the structure of the table you use for maintaining scores - DDL. Give us some data DML. Use dbfiddle.uk. You don't need 24 tables - probably!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a `MonthOf` and `YearOf` column (likely as integer types) to your `Leaderboard` table? Then you'll only need one table to store all the leaderboards. Whenever you need to show the `Leaderboard` for a particular month and year, you just add those fields as predicates in your `WHERE` clause of your query. E.g. `WHERE MonthOf = 1 AND YearOf = 2021` to get the `Leaderboard` for month of January 2021.

As Vérace mentioned, knowing which database system and version you're using, your `Leaderboard` table's current structure, and some sample data, would be helpful. But in any case, the above generic solution should generally work, and you should ensure the `MonthOf` and `YearOf` fields are part of an index for optimal execution of your queries.

Comment: I don't have a structure yet, but for example it should be something simple like: id, user_id, score. So if i add monthOf and yearOf columns, i should duplicate my user_id values, because same user can be in every month in leaderboard

Comment: @BobbyRedjeans correct, that sounds like a reasonable table definition for your use case. And again, I'd recommend creating an index on `(YearOf, MonthOf)` and possibly on `(User_Id)` or `(User_Id, YearOf, MonthOf)` depending on what queries you'll be running against it.